# Need to skip a part/argument on shell script for my testing without if/else conditions

Tags: linux, shell, unix, redis

- I have to test a redis connection by using scripts with out if/else
  conditions. Below if else condition works fine for me to establish
  redis connection. But I want to use another method which comes as a
  client requirement.

I have a code with if/else condition (If is for Travis test & else is    prod code). Instead of using if/else condition I need to skip TLS    verification.

```
if [[ ! -z $TRAVIS_TEST ]]; then
    ${REDLI} --host=${REDIS_ENDPOINT} --port=${REDIS_PORT} --redisuser=${REDIS_USERNAME} --auth=${REDIS_PASSWORD} <<ExitFromRedliTRAVIS
    exit
ExitFromRedliTRAVIS
    conn_retcode=$?
else
#Prod version
    ${REDLI} --tls --certfile=${REDIS_CERT_FILE} --host=${REDIS_ENDPOINT} --port=${REDIS_PORT} --redisuser= ${REDIS_USERNAME} --auth=${REDIS_PASSWORD} <<ExitFromRedli
    exit
```

So same line can’t be used twice with a minor changes. Minor change is for my TRAVIS test is `--tls --certfile=${REDIS_CERT_FILE}` this needs to be skipped and rest of the line needs to execute for my Travis test, If not full command needs to be executed for my production. So I tried `$()`

```
${REDLI} --tls --certfile=${REDIS_CERT_FILE} --host=${REDIS_ENDPOINT} --port=${REDIS_PORT} --redisuser= ${REDIS_USERNAME} --auth=${REDIS_PASSWORD} $([ ! -z "$TRAVIS_TEST" ] && echo "--tls --certfile=${REDIS_CERT_FILE}") <<ExitFromRedli && ExitFromRedliTRAVIS
```

But it fails with redli as # redli: error: flag 'tls' cannot be repeated, try --help any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
[[ $TRAVIS_TEST ]] || cert="--tls --certfile=${REDIS_CERT_FILE}"
${REDLI} $cert --host=${REDIS_ENDPOINT} --port=${REDIS_PORT} --redisuser=${REDIS_USERNAME} --auth=${REDIS_PASSWORD}
```